# Elabore um programa que receba uma linha de texto e conte as vogais apresentando o respectivo histogram

Tags: python

exercico: Elabore um programa que receba uma linha de texto e conte as vogais apresentando o respectivo histogram a na seguinte forma:

> Exemplo:  Linha de texto passada: “Na próxima quarta-f eira é
>   feriado.”

```
 a :  ****** (6) 
 e :  *** (3) 
 i :  *** (3)  
 o :  ** (2) 
 u :  * (1)
```

fiz da seguinte forma:

```
texto = 'na proxima quarta-feira é feriado'
a = texto.count('a')

print('a:','*'*a,'(',a,')')
```

do jeito que fiz faz exatamente oque o exercício pede porem eu teria que fazer vogal por vogal. Gostaria de saber de um jeito mais pratico de fazer porque por exemplo se o exercício pedisse letras do alfabeto todo ficaria muito grande para fazer tudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você iterar por todas as vogais e colocar a lógica dentro do loop.

```
texto = 'na proxima quarta-feira é feriado'
for vogal in 'aeiou':
    n = texto.count(vogal)
    print('a:', '*' * n, '(', n, ')')
```

Não esqueça que a sua lógica só vai funcionar para letras minúsculas e sem acento.

Se quisesse fazer por todas as letras sem ter que escrever todo o alfabeto, o Python oferece uma lista de caracteres pronta:

```
from string import ascii_letters
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!